# Access mongodb by Robomongo in Virtualbox hosted Ubuntu

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, ubuntu, meteor

I am trying to access Mongodb in the virtualbox hosted Ubuntu. When I am developing app in Ubuntu, I used "meteor create {app_name}"

I didnt change the default Mongodb. So when I am running Meteor app using "meteor" command, I cant access the mongodb.

In my Robomongo app in Windows, I am using this credentials,

"192.168.1.13:3001" as host and port. But It says "failed to connect".

What Do i need to do to connect to my mongodb?

Comment: do you want to connect your robomongo with the same machine in which you have database ? or you want to connect it in some different machine?

Comment: My robomongo app is in windows. Virtualbox is installed in that windows, and virtualbox virtually host Ubuntu os. and the database are in the ubuntu os.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hey After doing some digging I find out the solution.

steps you need to follow:

1. Go to the following path `cd /etc`
2. There you will find a file called **mongod.conf** open this file with the help of

**sudo vim mongod.conf**

3.You will be in a file type i and find bindIp written over there.

4.now you need to change your bindIp of mongodb to 0.0.0.0

5.type **ctrl +c** then **:wq** // write and quite

6.sudo service mongod restart

7.Go to your robomongo and create connection and in address field just type your ip (192.168.1.13) // no port number is required in which you are running the code port will be default port on which mongodb runs 27017

Comment: you have to put IP of your ubuntu in your windows robomongo. have you followed all the above steps what issue are you facing ?

Comment: Same "Failed to connect". I used 192.168.1.13.  In number 4 step above, Is it really 0.0.0.0?

Comment: It should have worked but just try it with 0.0.0.0 it actually allows your mongodb to connect to any ip for authentication you can  use mongo auth.

Comment: I didnt install mongodb manually. when I install Meteor, I just use meteor create, then I can store documents in a collection. So the mongodb is default. I didnt deploy the meteor app so it still in development. Do it have an effect on this issue?

Comment: no this can't be if you are able to save data in collection if should not be an issue. I am able to do this by following these steps just remember to set bindIp to 0.0.0.0 and restart mongod service by 'sudo service mongod restart'

Comment: To make this work in my Robomongo, I need to use 127.0.0.1 and port 3001. in my conf file, i have 127.0.0.1 and port of 3001

Answer (score 0):

I have found that using no bind ip in mongod.conf and adding localhost 127.0.0.1 to the hosts.conf works